# How to split a giant div into multiple divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a task that I am not sure how best to do it. So I would like some input or suggestions :)

Alright, so here is what I need to do.

I have a page with content being sent to the print (it contains images, and text in divs, p, span, h1, h2, h3, hr, a etc tags). And let's say it is roughly 1500 pixels high.

I have a container div say 300 by 500 pixels.

I need to take the page with all of the content, and split up that content into the divs.

So:

```
_______________
|              |
|              |
|              |
|   Content    |
|              |
|              |
|              |
|______________|
```

Goes into:

```
_______________
|   Part 1     |
|______________|
|   Part 2     |
|______________|
|   Part 3     |
|______________|
|   Part 4     |
|______________|
```

But my problem comes with how do I take a giant object of multiple elements on a page and go through it and determine that this div should be cut in half and placed in part 1 and part 2 because it can't fit in the remaining space in part 1? And how do I determine what is remaining and what isn't?

My thought was to read the entire contents of the body tag into a variable, looping through each element and adding it to another variable which would have remaining space, I could determine that based on the DOM elements height and width. But I'm not sure if that is the best idea.

Comment: ooo, pagination formulas are a pain. you'll need a steady pattern to follow so you can break down the elements into new div containers, measure height and width, and when one reach max or is overextended, remove its last added element and start the next. Good luck.

Comment: are you trying to make a print css or what's the purpose of this? or is this like some kind of test question where it asks you to divide the page up into different sections?

Comment: The purpose of this is taking a recipe (full page) and altering it for different sizes. And I need to do it client side. Sadly it's not a test, :(

Comment: What kind of different sizes?

Comment: For example 300x400, though that should be configurable because I have multiple sizes depending on a url parameter.

Comment: is there any standard structure to the content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using a brute force type approach is not out of the question, then using something like following should work:

- Put everything in div 1
- Start taking things from div 1 into div 2 until div 1 is of the correct size
- Repeat process for div 2

An alternative approach would be to loop through each node in the div, summing the total height until it exceeds the limit. At that point, take a step back and start moving the content to the next div, repeating the process.

If your page has a lot of text in a single text node, then it may be a bit tricky. You would most likely need to implement some kind of system to split text nodes in order to be able to calculate the height of individual text blocks and to be able to split them between divs.

Comment: I'd be rather sceptical about summing the lengths "manually", you'd have to take care about padding/margins/borders, and it would probably derail completely on a `position` property (if it appeared there, of course). Letting the layout engine do the reflow seems more straightforward, complete and less error prone.

For separate elements in the div you might try to play with CSS `display` property instead of taking moving elements around.

Comment: @peterph those are indeed valid concerns with this sort of stuff. However, at least for margins/borders there should be a way to determine it with JS pretty easily. Obviously anything which is positioned outside the normal flow will break it. In order to paginate such elements, it might be required to just make them positioned normally, or you would need to separately determine whether such elements clip the box.

Comment: @Steven yeah I would try to iterate each text node. If there isn't enough nodes, try taking a text node and split it into two or more parts, just split it in the middle or so until you have enough of them to work with.

Comment: I think I'm going to investigate the second one. Luckily my content is pretty much the same on all the pages, only 3 different styles and all follows the same flow. Thanks!