# On click split my square div in equal parts continously in equal matrix matrix form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very new on this site and found it very interesting...
Actually,I want splitting of div in equal matrix form,that I have already taken.On clicking anywhere inside it...
For. example-
1)On first click my div will split into 2 X 2 parts..
2)On second click  my div will split into 3 X 3 parts..
 And so on upto n X n..

I have already searched it on google,but unfortunately i hve not found any script as a solution for it..Thanks a lot for replying in advance..

```
<div  class="main_div" style="width:500px;height:500px;background-color:#9F0;">

 </div>
```

Comment: Could you share some code you tried?

Comment: ok! by saying 2X2 do you mean into two divs, like
<div  class="main_div"></div><div  class="main_div"></div>

Comment: No!By two divs I mean spliting of same "main_div" class in 2 X 2 form i.e in 4 equal parts and so on...
Thanks,for replying..

Comment: What would be the 4 part html code you are expecting? Could you write the output html?

Comment: Currently let's say any colourfull 4 different divs,then 9 and so on...

Comment: Give us the output html you want at 2X2 form. Do you mean something like this [How to split a giant div into multiple divs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297080/how-to-split-a-giant-div-into-multiple-divs)

Comment: @cforcloud-Not same..But,similar like it..<div  class="main_div" style="width:500px;height:500px;background-color:#9F0;">
 <div class="part" style="width:250px;height:250px;background-color:#9C0;float:left;">
 </div>
 <div class="part" style="width:250px;height:250px;background-color:#9F0;float:left;">
 </div>
 <div class="part" style="width:250px;height:250px;background-color:#F00;float:left;">
 </div>
  <div class="part" style="width:250px;height:250px;background-color:#990;float:left;">
 </div>
</div>

Comment: On 1st click my above code is exactly what i am expecting as in output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try.
If you need to do this for some graphics purpose, use [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) or [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas)

Random Colors courtesy : http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/

```js
var no = 1, $m = $(".main_div"), size = 180;

$m.click(function(){
    no++;
    var i, _no = no * no, _size = size/no;
    $m.empty();

    for(i=0; i<_no; i++)
        $m.append(
            $('<div title='+ i +'/>')
            .css('background-color', '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16))
        );

    $m.find('> div').css({ width:_size, height:_size });

});
```

```css
.main_div {
    width:180px;
    height:180px;
    background-color:#9F0;
}
.main_div > div {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main_div"></div>
```

Comment: @Cforcloud-Thanks a ton for the answer...this is exactly what i was  looking for..Can u plz do me one last favor can u plz share fiddle code of the same because i don't no why it's not working after copying the same code in my system...Thank u so much one again..

Comment: Click on the 'Run code snippet' button seen right above to see output

Comment: @Cforcloud-It's working now...Thanks a ton for giving ur valuable time...:-)